# How to set flash succes message in sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i'm looking for a way to set flash message in admin controller of sonata admin bundle.

I tried to overriding the postPersist function in my admin class, and adding the message in the Symfony flash bag.

```
    public function postPersist($object)
    {
        $flashbag  = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag();

        $flashbag->set('sonata_flash_success',
            $this->trans(
                'flash_create_success',
                [
                    '%name%' =>  $object->getCode(),
                    '%id%' =>  $object->getId()
                ],
                'SonataAdminBundle'
            )
        );
    }
```

My problem is that i got 2 flash messages instead of one. i just need to show the customized message (the one I just added).
How can i do please to remove the one set by default ?

appreciate your help

Comment: A little bit hacky but you can remove the content of the sonata success flash message before set your own message with a `$flashbag->get('sonata_flash_success')` ([because accessing to a flash removes it](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBag.php#L81) if you don't assign it to a variable) then `$flashbag->add('sonata_flash_success', 'your message')`.

Comment: @UgoT. I still have the sonata success flush message. I noticed that postPersist function is called before the flush message was created and set in CRUDController action. I think that the last solution is to override the  createAction in `\Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController` and try to set flush message inside.